# Where does Aizen make this quote about self-rightfulness?

Tags: bleach

I was looking for one specific quote from Sousuke Aizen but I was not able to find it, I googled it and watch some of the scenes that I believe he says it but didn't really find it.

If I recall correctly I believe he says it to Ukitake and I think it goes something like this:

> "...You are blinded by your self-rightfulness..."

Or something like that but I wanted to remember it correctly and the context of which it happened. If someone remembers it properly it would greatly appreciated!

Comment: (To Ichigo Kurosaki) "I suppose it is only to be expected. You have my pity. There is no such thing as 'truth' or 'lies' in this world; there never has been. There is only plain, hard facts. And yet, all beings who exist in this world take only those 'facts' that are convenient to them, and take them to be the 'truth'. They do so because they know no other way to live. However, for those powerless beings that make up the majority of this world it is those 'facts' that are inconvenient for their own self-affirmation that make up the real 'truth'."  maybe?

Comment: Check this link, although fan-made but it contains the stuff you're looking for. https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9555110/1/A-Fateful-Encounter
P.S.:Check the last 3-4 paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in episode 62.

> Ukitake asks "Have you become that corrupt? Have you?"
>
> Aizen replies: "You're blinded by your self-righteousness. From the beginning,
> no one has ever stood at the top. Neither you, nor me, nor the gods.
> But soon, that unobtainable vacancy at the top will be filled."

Here is the [link](http://youtu.be/sPFb9gv6deI?t=12m10s) to the moment you are referring to.

Comment: I think you have small typo, its "Have you become that corrupt? have you?"

Comment: You are right :) I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

> (To Shinji Hirako)
>
> "It is the nature of all living things to find some being greater than themselves and place their trust in that being, following it blindly. In order to escape from the pressure of that trust, those beings seek a still greater entity in which to believe, and those greater beings too seek still greater, still stronger beings to follow. This is how all kings come to be, and this is how all Gods are born. Do not trust in me yet, Hirako Shinji. I will take my time to teach you the nature of the God whom you face. Then, you shall believe."
>
> - Chapter 383, pages 17-18

This might not be what you are thinking of but it was the only quote that I could find on following something blindly.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of a scene near the end of the Soul Society arc, where Aizen and his cohorts are escaping through a Garganta. He looks down on the Shinigami from inside his Negacion and says something like:

> You're too proud, Ukitake. From the beginning, there was no one in Heaven. Not gods, not angels, not men. But that will soon change. From now on...I will stand in Heaven.